# How to install hd on centos?

Tags: yum

```
$ hd test.bin
00000000  e8 06 00 00 00 74 65 73  74 0a 00 b8 04 00 00 00  |.....test.......|
00000010  bb 01 00 00 00 59 ba 05  00 00 00 cd 80 c3        |.....Y........|
```

`hd` is supposed to be able to read hex,but how to install it?

Here's what I tried:

```
$# yum install hd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
 * base: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
 * epel: mirror.bjtu.edu.cn
 * extras: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
 * updates: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
Setting up Install Process
No package hd available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: If you don't know the package name you can also install by path, e.g. try `yum install /usr/bin/hd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hexdump(1)` is in the `util-linux` package.